# Optimal way to iterate over rows from Oracle in C# Multi thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, loops, select

I'm using a Oracle 12c database and I wonder which is the optimal way to  iterate in C# over the result of a select query. Once I get the row values I use it to do some work.

My idea is to use the full processor capacity so I thought I need one thread per cpu core, each thread would have his own connection, which is use to get (select count(*) from table where condition)/(cores) rows and then each thread makes the work.

Each table has more 500000 rows.

Am I right or there is a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance, and I'm apology for my English.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: It depends on what the user want to do. For example sometimes the data is the x of equation, which result is used for update the value of the row which I get from the db and do some insertions on another table.

Answer (score 0):

It all DEPENDS... :).

Does it all sits on the same box? Oracle and your program?

If not then the number of connections SHOULD NOT be the function of the number of the CPU cores! It should depend on your network infrastructure, the number of connections between the box with your program and the box with your database. Sometimes even on one physical connection is possible to get higher throughput with multiple DB connections, but it has own limits and is useful as long as the DB does not provide maximum resources to one request, rather sharing resources to multiple requests and in case, when generating requests takes time per each generated row of the result. But that is best decided by benchmarking.

If your program and database are sharing the same box, then it is the different scenario. In such case, I would in general use on the side of my app less or equally half of the cores available, as the DB needs cores for processing too and the big number of result rows comes in continually...

It also depends on what you do next with the rows.

Comment: In my development environment I use everything in the same box, but in production the idea is to have at least one box for the database. 
As I commented to tbone above what I do next with the rows depends of what the user wanna to do.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you sure you need to bring back 500,000 rows to your application to process? How about doing the processing in the database ?

Comment: Maybe it could be posible to do it on the database, but I don't find an easy way to specify every processing witch the final user could specify on a DSL, from witch I get the information to do C# program. I'm considering you are talking about PL/SQL programming?